# cURL Libraries on Ubuntu 9.10 Server Running SugarCRM Causing Problems with Scheduler

Tags: ubuntu, curl, sugarcrm

Running Ubuntu 9.10, Apache 2.2, MySQL 5.1.37, PHP 5.2.10, SugarCRM Pro 5.5.4

I started out by trying to use a Sugar function call Scheduler and Sugar complained:

``` This system does not have the cURL libraries enabled/compiled into the PHP module (--with-curl=/path/to/curl_library). Please contact your administrator to resolve this issue. ``Without the cURL functionality, the Scheduler cannot thread its jobs. ```

I confirmed curl, libcurl packages are installed on the system.

But now I am having trouble finding out what file to point to in the `php.ini` file.  Some forums say I need a `php_curl.so` file (similar to the `php_curl.dll` in Windows) but I can only find `curl.so`.  Where do I change the `extension_dir=/path/to/libraries` to point to?

Since I don't have a `php_curl.so` file, should I make the `extension=` to `curl.so`?

Some output when I restarted my `apache2` is here:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './php_curl.so' - ./php_curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './curl.so' - ./curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './gd.so' - ./gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './mcrypt.so' - ./mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './mysql.so' - ./mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './mysqli.so' - ./mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './pdo.so' - ./pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './pdo_mysql.so' - ./pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall php5-curl like so:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-curl
```

Comment: I have tried this several times through the Synaptic and the terminal.  I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it too.  Is this command special in anyway, like the `--reinstall` switch?  Or will reinstalling it the way(s) I did be sufficient?

Comment: The way you did should be the same. You can also try remove and purge the package, but I'm not confident this will help. Do you use a custom compiled PHP?

Comment: I just got it...  I hadn't touched this issue since last week, and I went back and restarted the Apache 2 server, and my issue is gone.  The curl libraries are loaded and my error has vanished.  I'm not sure if the reinstall did it or if it was something else.  Thanks for the help nonetheless!